# Не печатать перевод строки

Tags: php

Есть текст на входе:

```
текст<br />
текст
```

Печатаю его через echo, выдаёт то что нужно

```
текст
текст
```

Но нужно пропустить его через класс:

```
class IRB_BBdecoder
{

private $bb_open;
private $bb_close;    
private $bb_single;                                                       
private $html_open;
private $html_close;
private $html_single;
private $tmp_open;
private $tmp_close;
private $tmp_single;
private $max_len;

public function __construct()
{
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) .'/config.php';

    extract($configBBcode);
    $this->bb_open      = array_keys($setup_bb);
    $this->bb_close     = array_values($setup_bb);                                                        
    $this->html_open    = array_keys($setup_html);
    $this->html_close   = array_values($setup_html);
    $this->bb_single    = array_keys($single_tags);
    $this->html_single  = array_values($single_tags);

    $this->tmp_open    = $tmp_open;
    $this->tmp_close   = $tmp_close;
    $this->tmp_single  = $tmp_single;
    $this->max_len     = $max_len;
}
public function createBBtags($text)
{

    $text = str_replace($this->tmp_open, '', $text);
    $text = str_replace($this->tmp_close, '', $text);
    $text = str_replace($this->tmp_single, '', $text);

    $text = str_replace("\r", "", $text);
    $text = str_replace("\t", "    ", $text);

    $text = str_ireplace($this->bb_open, $this->tmp_open, $text);
    $text = str_ireplace($this->bb_close, $this->tmp_close, $text);
    $text = str_ireplace($this->bb_single, $this->tmp_single, $text);

    $open_cnt = array();

    foreach($this->tmp_open as $k => $v)
    {
       $text = preg_replace("#". $v ."\s*?". $this->tmp_close[$k] ."#us", "", $text);
       $cnt = substr_count($text, $v);

       if($cnt > 0)
       {
           $open_cnt[$v] = $cnt;
           $close_cnt[$v] = substr_count($text, $this->tmp_close[$k]);
       }              
    }

    foreach($open_cnt as $k => $v)
    {

        if($v > $close_cnt[$k])
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < $v - $close_cnt[$k]; ++$i)
                $text = preg_replace('#'. $k .'(?!.*'. $k .')#us', '', $text);
        }

    }

    $text = $this->mBwordwrap($text, $this->max_len);

    $text = str_replace($this->tmp_open, $this->html_open, $text);
    $text = str_replace($this->tmp_close, $this->html_close, $text);
    $text = str_replace($this->tmp_single, $this->html_single, $text);

    $text = str_replace('  ', '&nbsp;&nbsp;', $text);    
    $text = nl2br($text);

    return $text;            
}

public function stripBBtags($text)
{
    $text = str_replace($this->bb_open, '', $text);
    $text = str_replace($this->bb_close, '', $text);
    $text = str_replace($this->bb_single, '', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('#\[(code|url|img|video)[^\s]*?\].*?\[/\\1\]#usi', '', $text);     
    return $text;
}

public function mBwordwrap($text, $width = 74, $break = "\n")
{
   return preg_replace('#([^\s]{'. $width .'})#u', '$1'. $break , $text);
}

}
```

Пропускаю так:

```
    $bb = new IRB_BBdecoder;

    $text = !empty($out) ? $out : NULL;
    $check = $bb -> stripBBtags($text);

        echo $bb -> createBBtags($text);
```

На выходе имею:

```
текст

текст
```

Тоесть печатается два br. Первый бр, оно и понятно, написан в тексте, а вот второй берётся из самого переноса. Как исправить? Ведь простым echo печатается всё правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и должно быть жеж. В коде:

```
$text = nl2br($text);
```

Удалите эту строку. а под `$text = str_replace("\t", "    ", $text);` добавьте

```
$text = str_replace("\n", "", $text);
```

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил nl2br ))